# Spark: After CollectAsMap() or Collect(), every entry has same value

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I need to read a text file and change this file to Map.
When I make JavaPairRDD, it works well.

However, when I change JavaPairRDD to Map, every entry has same value, more specifically the last data in text file.

inputFile:

```
1 book:3000
2 pencil:1000
3 coffee:2500
```

When I read a text file, I used Hadoop custom input format. 

Using this format, Key is number and Value is custom class **Expense<content,price>**.

JavaPairRDD<Integer,Expense> inputRDD = JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(inputFile, ExpenseInputFormat.class, Integer.class, Expense.class, HadoopConf);

inputRDD:

```
[1, (book,3000)]
[2, (pencil,1000)]
[3, (coffee,2500)]
```

However, when I do 

Map<Integer,Expense> inputMap = new HashMap<Integer,Expense>(inputRDD.collectAsMap());

inputMap:

```
[1, (coffee,2500)]
[2, (coffee,2500)]
[3, (coffee,2500)]
```

As we can see, key is correctly inserted, but every value is the last value of input.
I don't know why it happens..

Comment: Could you share a complete example with us. I tried to reproduce your problem, but I couldn't. Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for advising, I removed that sentence.

Comment: @TillRohrmann Thank you for answering, I changed it more specifically. And I use Spark 1.4.1.

Comment: How does your `ExpenseInputFormat` look like?